# S3 as one CloudFront origin, API Gateway as another, how to ensure API Gateway is only accessible through CloudFront serving the S3 static website

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, cloud

Consider an architecture where an S3 bucket serves as one origin of a CloudFront distribution, and an API Gateway serves as another origin for the same CloudFront distribution. How can I configure this setup so that direct calls to the API Gateway origin are disabled? I want to ensure that the API Gateway is only accessible through the CloudFront distribution that also hosts a static website on the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by injecting a custom HTTP header to origin requests on Cloudfront and then checking that header by configuring the corresponding API key on API Gateway.
[This AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/protecting-your-api-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-waf-part-2/) explains how to do it.

[image: protecting API Gateway access using API keys]

**Note**: The blog also goes into integrating WAF with Cloudfront and API Gateway. If you are using HTTP API Gateway (and not REST API Gateway), [you will not be able to integrate WAF with API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html). You can always of course use WAF with Cloudfront though.

If you are not concerned about WAF integration, here is another great blog: [Protecting APIs with custom headers in CloudFront](https://arpadt.com/articles/protecting-apis-with-cloudfront).